# Show that $f(x)$ is a constant function if $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x+t)\cdot t\,dt=0$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, such that for any real number $x$ we have:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{1}{h^3}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x+t)\cdot t\,dt=0.$$
Show that $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Maybe we can use the following lemma?

**Lemma**. If $g$ is a continuous function, then
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2\,h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}g(s)\,ds=g(x).$$

**Proof**. We may assume $h>0$.
$$
\left|g(x)-\frac{1}{2\,h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}g(s)\,ds\right|=\frac{1}{2\,h}\left|\int_{x-h}^{x+h}(g(x)-g(s))\,ds\right|\le\frac{1}{2\,h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}\left|g(x)-g(s)\right|\,ds.$$
Use that $g$ is continuous at $x$ to show that the last expression converges to $0$ as $h\to0$.

Comment: Please don't change the statement of the question after users have already thought about your problem. It's okay to make a separate question for the case $h^3$. The question with $h^2$ is very nice, and you got a good answer showing why it is false.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: If there is a simple counter example such as $f(x) = x$ then I would suspect a typo, and ask for clarification in a comment. But there are surely different opinions on that.

Comment: Why are you looking for "an answer from a reputable source"? You already have two answers to your revised statement.

Comment: it's from china nanjing Nanjing University constant problem

Comment: @inequality: Is there any other assumption on $f$? for example, $f$ is lipschitz?

Comment: Taking the Fourier transform of $f$ seems fruitful, but the integrability conditions may be just as difficult to justify as the proposition that $f$ is differentiable. I didn't give it much thought.

Comment: I think that Paresseux Nguyen's answer, which is a wonderful piece of analysis, should be accepted.

Comment: It is also a pity that the question author did not care to award the bounty.

Comment: Lol, It's the first time I see a bounty of +25.

Comment: @NN2: No, the bounty was for 50 points. But inequality did not *award* the bounty (or accept an answer). In that case, half of the amount is automatically assigned to the highest voted answer that was posted during the bounty period.

Answer (score 18):

Define $F (x):= \int_{0}^x f(t)dt$

By integration by parts, we observe that:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-h}^h f(x+t)tdt &= \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^h \big[ f(x+t)-f(x-t)]tdt\\& = F(x+h)+F(x-h)  -  \frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^h \big[ F(x+t)+F(x-t) \big]dt
\end{align}$$
So the provided limit for f implies that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$T(F)(x)=0$$
Where  $T$ is an operator defined as
$$T(g)(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{h^2} \left\{ g(x+h)+g(x-h)-\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^h \big[ g(x+t)+g(x-t)\big]dt \right\} $$
for any continuous function $g$.
Note that $T(g)$ is not necessarily defined on all points in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon$ be any positive number , $(a,b)$ be any interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Define the functions
$$G(x)= F(x)-F(a)-\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}(x-a)+\epsilon(x-a)(x-b)$$
and
$$H(x)= F(x)-F(a)-\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}(x-a)\boldsymbol{-}\epsilon(x-a)(x-b)$$

We prove that $G(x) \le 0$ everywhere on $[a,b]$. If not then, because $G(a)=G(b)=0$, there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ at which $G$ attains its positive maximum. Observe that:
$$T(G)(c)= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{h^2} \left\{ G(c+h)+G(c-h)-\frac{1}{h}\int_{0}^h \big[ G(c+t)+G(c-t)\big]dt \right\} $$
Because $c$ is a maxima of $G$, the function $u(t):=G(c+t)+G(c-t)$ attains its local maximum  at $t=0$. So we can choose a strictly decreasing positive sequence $(h_n, n \in \mathbb{N})$ such that $h_n$ converge to $0$ and $h_n \in \text{argmin}_{ t \in [0,h_n]} u(t)$ for all $n$ . Thus,
$$ G(c+h_n)+G(c-h_n)-\frac{1}{h_n}\int_{0}^{h_n} \big[ G(c+t)+G(c-t)\big]dt \le 0$$
Thus $T(G)(c) \le 0$. Note that the limit $T(G)(c)$  exists because $T(F)$ exists and in fact, according to the definition, we see that:
$$T(G)(c)=0+0+\frac{4}{3}\epsilon>0 $$
Which is a contradiction to what we have just proven.

So $G(x) \le 0$ on $[a,b]$. Similarly, we can prove that $H(x) \ge 0$ everywhere on $[a,b]$. These give:
$$ \left|   F(x)-F(a)-\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}(x-a) \right| \le \epsilon (b-a)^2$$
for all $\epsilon>0$ and $x \in [a,b]$. Hence forth the conclusion.

*Side note:* The hypothesis is fairly tight as we can show that the Cantor function satisfies the condition on an **almost** everywhere set of $\mathbb{R}$ even though it is not constant.

Comment: Your argument is not entirely clear to me. $u$ has a maximum at $t=0$, but why does that imply that $u(h_n) - \frac 1 {h_n} \int_0^{h_n} u(t) dt \le 0$ on a sequence $h_n \searrow 0$? – And $h_n \in \text{argmin}_{ t \in [0,h_n]} u(t)$ looks like a cyclic definition to me.

Comment: @MartinR The latter part is where I started. That existence of the sequence $(h_n)$ is can be shown by the following construction. 
$$\begin{align}  h_1 &\in \text{argmin}_{t \in [0,b-a]}\\{0\} u(t)  \\ h_{n+1} &\in \text{argmin}_{ t \in [0, \text{min}(h_n,1/n)] } u(t) \end{align} \{0\}$$

Comment: That is not exactly what you wrote in the answer. – And how do you get from that definition to $u(h_n) - \frac 1 {h_n} \int_0^{h_n} u(t) dt \le 0$? Perhaps I am overlooking something simple ...

Comment: That is beause $u(h_n)=\text{min}_{ t \in [0,h_n]} u(t)$, in other words, $ u(h_n) \le u(t) \forall 0 \le t \le h_n$.  So $u(h_n) \le \frac{1}{h_n} \int_{0}^{h_n} u(t)dt$

Comment: (I repost this comment because I was not allowed to edit this one). The latter part is where I started. That existence of the sequence (ℎ) is can be shown by the following construction. $$\begin{align} h_1 &\in [\text{argmin}_{t \in [0,b-a]} u(t)]\backslash \{ 0\} \\ h_{n+1} &\in [\text{argmin}_{ t \in [0, \text{min}(h_n,1/n)] } u(t)]\backslash \{ 0\} \end{align} $$

Comment: With that definition is $u(h_{n+1})=\text{min}_{ t \in [0,h_n]} u(t)$, which gives you “only” $u(h_{n+1}) \le \frac{1}{h_n} \int_{0}^{h_n} u(t)dt$

Comment: If $u(h_{n+1}) =\text{min}_{t  \in [0,h_n] } u(t)$, then $u(h_{n+1}) =\text{min}_{t  \in [0,h_{n+1}] } u(t)$ because $0 \le h_{n+1} \le h_n$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen: Now I see it, excellent!

Answer (score 10):

Prove me wrong, but I think the statement is false. Consider the example $f(x)=x$, which is clearly continuous and fulfills. For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{gather*}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^2}\int_{-h}^hf(x+t)t\,\mathrm dt=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^2}\int_{-h}^h(x+t)t\,\mathrm dt=x\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^2}\int_{-h}^ht\,\mathrm dt+\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{h^2}\int_{-h}^ht^2\,\mathrm dt\\
= x \lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{h^2}\left(\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{h^2}{2}\right) + \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h^2}\left(\frac{h^3}{3} - \frac{-h^3}{3}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{2}{3} h = 0.
\end{gather*}

Comment: I'm very very sorry,it's $h^3$, I have edit

Answer (score 4):

I can provide a straightforward answer, if $f$ is additionally differentiable. Then, there holds

$$\int_{-h}^hf(x+t)tdt = \int_{-h}^h (f(x)+f'(x)t+o(t))t dt = f(x)\left(\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{h^2}{2}\right) + f'(x)\left(\frac{h^3}{3}-\frac{-h^3}{3}\right) + o(h^3) = f'(x) \frac{2}{3} h^3 + o(h^3).$$

Consequently,

$$0=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{-h}^hf(x+t)tdt = \frac{2}{3} f'(x),$$

thus $f$ is constant. The general case can maybe treated with an argumentation similar to that of Marco Cantarini.

Comment: I have the feeling that it is considerably more difficult if $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable. Marco Cantarini's argument had a flaw, he has deleted his answer in the meantime.

Comment: polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions $C([-1,1])$, and they are smooth, so using this probably you can prove the original result

Answer (score -2):

If $f(x)$ is continuous in $\textbf{R}$, then we can write
$$
\int^{h}_{0}f(x+t)tdt-\int^{-h}_{0}f(x+t)tdt=\int^{h}_{0}(f(x+t)-f(x-t))tdt.
$$
Hence from remark below (and for all $x$ real) we have
$$
0=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int^{h}_{0}(f(x+t)-f(x-t))tdt=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{3h}.\tag 1
$$
Clearly about (1) we have:
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h^{-1}\int^{h}_{0}(f(x+t)-f(x-t))tdt=0
$$
Set
$$
F(y):=y^{-1}\int^{y}_{0}(f(x+t)-f(x-t))tdt,
$$
then $F(y)$ is continuous and differentiatable in $\textbf{R}$ with $F(0)=0$ and $F'(0)=0$. This last follows from the fact that $F(y)$ is differentiable in all $\textbf{R}-\{0\}$ and from problem condition:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(y)}{y}=0.
$$
Also:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}F'(y)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\left(f(x+y)-f(x-y)-\frac{F(y)}{y}\right)=0.
$$
All that since
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int^{h}_{0}\left(f(x+t)-f(x-t)\right)tdt=0.\tag 2
$$
Using the condition of the problem and Cauchy's mean value theorem (see below) we have
$$
0=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F(y)}{y^2}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F'(y)}{2y}=
$$
$$
=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\left(\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}-\frac{1}{2y^3}\int^{y}_{0}(f(x+t)-f(x-t))tdt\right)=
$$
$$
=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}=(f_{s})'_{+}(x).
$$
Also in the same way
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}=(f_{s})'_{-}(x).
$$
and $(f_s)'_{-}(x)=(f_s)'_{+}(x)=f_s'(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}$ exists. However there exists the

**Theorem.**

**I)** If for a function $f(x)$ the left $f'_{-}(x)$ and right $f'_{+}(x)$ derivatives exists, then $f'_s(x)$ exist and $f'_s(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f'_{-}(x)+f'_{+}(x))$.

**II)** If $f_s'(x)$ exist then it is not necessary that $f'(x)$ exist.

Hence we arrive to the result that
$$
f'_s(x)=0\textrm{, }\forall x\in\textbf{R}.\tag 3
$$
However (3) is not so well established since (5) is not applied to functions that  change sign infinite times in a neighborhood of $0$. For example
$$
F(y)=y^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right).
$$
The true argument [L'Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is that
$$
\textrm{liminf}_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}\leq 0\textrm{ and }\textrm{limsup}_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}\geq 0.\tag 4
$$

**Notes.**

From Cauchy mean value theorem in $[0,y]$, we have that exists always $\xi=\xi(y)$: $0<\xi(y)<y$ such that
$$
\frac{F(y)-F(0)}{y^2-0}=\frac{F'(\xi)}{2\xi}.
$$
Hence when $y\rightarrow 0^{+}$, from the continuity of
$$
\frac{F'(t)}{2t}=\frac{f(x+t)-f(x-t)}{2t}-\frac{1}{2t^3}\int^{t}_{0}(f(x+t_1)-f(x-t_1))t_1dt_1,
$$
in $(0,y)$ and knowing that $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F(y)}{y^2}=0$, $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\xi(y)=0$ we have
$$
0=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F(y)}{y^2}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F'(\xi(y))}{2\xi(y)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F'(t)}{2t}.\tag 5
$$
The same way is used when $y\rightarrow0^{-}$

Comment: It seems to me that you are applying L'Hospital's rule in the wrong direction: You argue that because  the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(h)}{G(h)} $ exists, the limit $ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F'(h)}{G'(h)}$ exists as well. But L'Hospital's rule is the other way around.

Comment: I think this is ok since it is given from the question.

Comment: Please explain how you get $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} = 0$.

Comment: ... and even if that were true, the next step is wrong because suddenly you assume that the limit is zero *uniformly* in $x$.

Comment: @NikosBagis: The use of L'Hospital is not correct here, as Martin R pointed out, unless one assumes that $f$ is symmetrically differentiable everywhere. In that case, it is a [deep](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1983-277-02/S0002-9947-1983-0694378-6/S0002-9947-1983-0694378-6.pdf)  result that $f$ found be constant (Theorem 5.2). In the generality of the OP ($f$ is simply continuous) some other argument may need to be used.

Comment: @OliverDiaz As by the extended mean value theorem, for every positive $h$, there exists $y\in]0,h[$ such that $h^{-3}\int_{-h}^h f(x+t)tdt=\frac1y(f(x+y)-f(x-y))$, Paresseux Nguyen's answer actually also provides a proof that any $f$ symmetrically differentiable everywhere with derivative 0 must be constant.

Comment: @Helmut: I've no problem with Parasseaux's solution. My critique was the erroneous used of L'Hospital's rule by other respodders.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Sorry, I was not clear enough. I meant to say that the deep result you mention is actually proved by Paresseux Nguyen's solution and I find it elementary (but ingenious).

Comment: @Helmut, I think the result I am referring to is more complicated. But it is irrelevant for the setting go the OP.